# Rails Design Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have a Post Model, and a comment Model. I would like to limit the comments to 3. How would you do this?

1. Would it be best to create a validation? If so what would this look
   like?
2. Would you do this in the view `unless Post.comments == 3`?
3. Would a callback make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the post's comments count validation is the "Comment" model responsibility, so I'd like to suggest the following code:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  before_create :limit_number

  private
  def limit_number
    if post.comments.count >= 3
      errors.add(:post, "the limit of comments is over")
    end
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

Comment: to provide the views functionality, you can use a helper method

Answer (score 3):

You should always validate at the model level as well as the views.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :post
  validate :check

  private

  def check
    if post.present?
      errors.add("Post", "can not have more than 3 comments") if post.comments.size >= 3
    end
  end

end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # other implementation...

  def commentable?
    comments.size <= 3
  end

end
```

Then just call `#commentable?` in your views like this. You should never hard-code values in the views.

```
<% if @post.commentable? %>
  <%= render "form" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure not to let them submit that fourth comment that you don't want to allow. Some might say you should do the check in your controller and pass a flag, but for something this simple the check in the view seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Validate it in the models.  You could use `validates_with` as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_with).

In the view, you'd be better off checking with an *inequality* like

```
unless Post.comments.length >= 3
  show_form
end
```

That way if you have four comments for some reason (race condition or an admin posts a response after 3, etc.) the form stils won't show up.